# CSS parse error (W3C Validator)

Tags: css

I have problem with css validating.

Adress of site is: www.programishta.pl/NK/

Please validate it, and help me :)

W3C CSS Validator says: 33 Parse Error baner

I can't find error :/

Link to CSS: http://programistha.pl/NK/CSS/style.css

Part of CSS:

```
#baner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    font-family: "Gnuolane", sans-serif;
    font-size: 72px;
    background-image: url("../Images/checkers.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 90% 15px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Comment: Which profile (CSS2.1, CSS3, ...) do you use for validation?

Comment: Do you have additional css in the page / inline-styles?

Answer (score 0):

When I validate the code at W3C, I get no errors

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fprogramistha.pl%2FNK%2FCSS%2Fstyle.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en